# A planet with 7 light sources

Tags: internal-consistency, earth-like, worldbuilding-process

How can a planet(with inhabitants) possible with 7 different sources of light and heat? They can be satellites, stars or anything. The temperature level should lies between  5°c to 25°c and most darkest time should be brighter as a earthly full moon and most brightest time should be like  10 am in a sunny earthly day.I it possible?
The size of the planet is similar to earth.
Is it possible if each light sources emits different colour of lights and and resulted light of 7 of them differ at different times?
Like greenish at early morning. Colorless at day time.. Red et evening and blue at night?

Edited [make edits to clarity my requirements]

Comment: This looks like a significant improvement over the version you asked a short while ago. In this case, I believe "satellites" would be the correct term - you can't have stars with less mass than Earth, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Related, if not possible duplicates, about luminous, low-mass planets/moons: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/13267/627, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/79430/627, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/34760/627.

Comment: the sun is not standing still. It orbits the galaxy center.

Comment: is it impossible to stay still? if so consider it orbited the galaxy centre.

Comment: @Prethika, it is not possible to stay completely still in space unless you throw the laws of physics out the window. planets orbit suns, or are rogue in which they orbit the Galactic Core, and galaxies themselves are moving through the void of space as the universe expands

Comment: I think you need to do one of the following: Either provide numbers, e.g. how bright are your "satellites", how large is your planet, how much mass does each body have and so on. If you don't know how to do that (why do you care then?), do a comparison, e.g. the satellites should be as small as a car but brighter than the full moon as seen from the planet. OR describe what you want to achieve and someone might be able to come up with a way to do it. Currently you have described neither your starting condition nor your result, so this is completely unanswerable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a moon on fire?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13267/how-can-i-set-a-moon-on-fire)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Prethika! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. Have fun!

Comment: @Renan These are related, not duplicates. Asking if it's possible to create a light-emiting moon is different from asking if there is a stable configuration of such satellites, as well as the impact on the host body of such satellites. The latter might be of _too broad_ concern, but it's not a duplicate of the first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the people of this planet hurried like hell to build an array of orbital nuclear reactors to work as light emitters before their world went rogue, yes, now there could be this vagabond planet lit up by his handmade 'stars'.

On the other hand, it is quite improbable that these satellites can make up for the light the mother stars used to radiate, so the world would be more like a cold place immersed in a perpetual twilight. Life would be harsh, but as long as these people can at least buy time to build greenhouses to feed themselves and use geothermal forces to get warmth, hey, better than dying I guess

Comment: There are only two self sustaining nuclear "reactors": stars (excluded by the OP), and nukes, which go off in milliseconds... all the others need constant care